# Fullcalendar, adding and removing event sources with checkbox

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I had this working in another way, but when I toggled a checkbox in list view, the dates show up even though the events dont.  So now I am coming at this from a different way using addEventSource and removeEventSource so that the dates are no longer rendered in list view.

Only problem is now when I click on a checkbox, nothing happens.  Any ideas?
In addition to the code below, I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ufjg8enh/2/) to make it easier to check it out.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var source99 = [

    {
      title: 'Lets see if this works',
      start: '2017-09-14T13:00:00',
      end: '2017-09-14T14:00:00',
      allDay: '',
      url: '',
      color: '#7dc5d7',
      catid: '99',
      cat: 'all-events',
    },

    {
      title: 'Another Test Event',
      start: '2017-09-20T13:00:00',
      end: '2017-09-20T14:00:00',
      allDay: '',
      url: '',
      color: '#7dc5d7',
      catid: '99',
      cat: 'all-events',
    },

  ];
  var source100 = [

    {
      title: 'Test',
      start: '2017-08-10T10:00:00',
      end: '2017-08-12T12:00:00',
      allDay: '',
      url: '',
      color: '#f98b22',
      catid: '100',
      cat: 'conferences',
    },

    {
      title: 'Conference Event',
      start: '2017-08-23T08:00:00',
      end: '2017-08-23T09:30:00',
      allDay: '',
      url: '',
      color: '#f98b22',
      catid: '100',
      cat: 'conferences',
    },

  ];
  var source101 = [

    {
      title: 'Skeet Shooting & Cookout',
      start: '2017-09-30',
      end: '2017-09-30',
      allDay: '1',
      url: '',
      color: '#4776fd',
      catid: '101',
      cat: 'men',
    },

    {
      title: 'Movie Night – “Greater”',
      start: '2017-09-01',
      end: '2017-09-01',
      allDay: '1',
      url: '',
      color: '#4776fd',
      catid: '101',
      cat: 'men',
    },

  ];
  var source102 = [

    {
      title: 'Some Women’s Event',
      start: '2017-08-23T08:00:00',
      end: '2017-08-23T09:30:00',
      allDay: '',
      url: '',
      color: '#b300ec',
      catid: '102',
      cat: 'women',
    },

  ];
  var source103 = [

    {
      title: 'A Youth Event',
      start: '2017-08-21T15:15:00',
      end: '2017-08-21T22:00:00',
      allDay: '',
      url: '',
      color: '#36e4bc',
      catid: '103',
      cat: 'youth',
    },

  ];

  // Build Calendar
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar({

    displayEventEnd: true,
    timeFormat: 'h:mm A',
    theme: true,
    //aspectRatio: 1.2,
    header: {
      left: 'basicWeek,listSixMonths,today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'prev,next'
    },

    defaultDate: '2017-08-22',
    defaultView: 'basicWeek',
    views: {
      basicWeek: {
        titleFormat: 'MMMM D, YYYY'
      },
      listWeek: {
        titleFormat: 'MMMM D, YYYY'
      },
      listSixMonths: {
        type: 'list',
        duration: {
          months: 6
        },
        buttonText: '6 Month List',
        titleFormat: 'MMMM D, YYYY'
      },
    },
    viewRender: renderViewColumns,
    eventSources: [
      source99,

      source100,

      source101,

      source102,

      source103,
    ]
  });

  // Create Checkboxes
  var checkboxContainer = `<ul class='ds-event-categories'>    
            <li id='cat99'><label><input id='all-events' type='checkbox' checked>All Events</label></li>
                <li id='cat100'><label><input id='conferences' type='checkbox' checked>Conferences</label></li>
                <li id='cat101'><label><input id='men' type='checkbox' checked>Men</label></li>
                <li id='cat102'><label><input id='women' type='checkbox' checked>Women</label></li>
                <li id='cat103'><label><input id='youth' type='checkbox' checked>Youth</label></li>
            </ul>`;

  // Append it to FullCalendar.
  $(".fc-toolbar").after(checkboxContainer);

  // Click handler

  $("#all-events").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'source99');
    } else {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', 'source99');
    }
  });

  $("#conferences").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'source100');
    } else {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', 'source100');
    }
  });

  $("#men").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'source101');
    } else {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', 'source101');
    }
  });

  $("#women").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'source101');
    } else {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', 'source101');
    }
  });

  $("#youth").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'source102');
    } else {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', 'source102');
    }
  });

  function renderViewColumns(view, element) {
    element.find('.fc-day-header').each(function() {
      var theDate = moment($(this).data('date')); /* th.data-date="YYYY-MM-DD" */
      $(this).html(buildDateColumnHeader(theDate));
    });

    function buildDateColumnHeader(theDate) {
      var container = document.createElement('div');
      var DD = document.createElement('div');
      var ddd = document.createElement('div');
      DD.textContent = theDate.format('DD');
      ddd.textContent = theDate.format('dddd').toUpperCase();
      container.appendChild(DD);
      container.appendChild(ddd);
      DD.className = 'ds-header-day';
      ddd.className = 'ds-header-month';

      return container;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured this out!  I want to give credit to [mikesmithdev](http://www.mikesmithdev.com/demo-fullcalendar-with-event-filtering) for some insight, however I have made some upgrades.  I'm sure there are still better ways, but this is working great at the moment.

**Smooth Render of Events**

Replaced refetchEvents with rerenderEVents.

Categories each have their own function so that all the events don't flash when a checkbox is clicked.

**Event Sources are Event Objects**

I found that the load time of events when clicking on and off, is seamless when using event objects rather than a link to a JSON feed (even hosted locally).

**No Longer Need Two Instances of the Events**

Since we are no longer loading events, removing all events on click, and reloading another version of events on click, we only need 1 version of events.

**Checkbox Filters inside Calendar**

I needed the checkboxes to be under the fc-toolbar.  I appended those so that they load nice and clean.

**Custom Column Headers for Week View**

I needed this to be a basicWeek view as default since there will be many events for each day.  This spruces it all up a bit.

**Here is the Updated JSFiddle**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ufjg8enh/3/)

**Here is my jQuery code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var eventSource = new Array();
eventSource[0] = [{"title":"Lets see if this works","start":"2017-09-14T13:00:00","end":"2017-09 14T14:00:00","allDay":true,"url":"","color":"#7dc5d7","catID":99,"cat":"all-events"},{"title":"Another Test Event","start":"2017-09-20T13:00:00","end":"2017-09-20T14:00:00","allDay":true,"url":"","color":"#7dc5d7","catID":99,"cat":"all-events"}];
eventSource[1] = [{"title":"Test","start":"2017-08-10T10:00:00","end":"2017-08-12T12:00:00","allDay":true,"url":"","color":"#f98b22","catID":100,"cat":"conferences"},{"title":"Conference Event","start":"2017-08-23T08:00:00","end":"2017-08-23T09:30:00","allDay":true,"url":"","color":"#f98b22","catID":100,"cat":"conferences"}];
eventSource[2] = [{"title":"Skeet Shooting & Cookout","start":"2017-09-30","end":"2017-09-30","allDay":true,"url":"","color":"#4776fd","catID":101,"cat":"men"},{"title":"Movie Night \u2013 \u201cGreater\u201d","start":"2017-09-01","end":"2017-09-01","allDay":true,"url":"","color":"#4776fd","catID":101,"cat":"men"}];
eventSource[3] = [{"title":"Some Women\u2019s Event","start":"2017-08-23T08:00:00","end":"2017-08-23T09:30:00","allDay":true,"url":"","color":"#b300ec","catID":102,"cat":"women"}];
eventSource[4] = [{"title":"A Youth Event","start":"2017-08-21T15:15:00","end":"2017-08-21T22:00:00","allDay":true,"url":"","color":"#36e4bc","catID":103,"cat":"youth"}];

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    displayEventEnd: true,
    timeFormat: 'h:mm A',
    theme: true,
    header: {
        left: 'basicWeek,listSixMonths,today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'prev,next'
    },
    defaultDate: '2017-08-23',
    defaultView: 'basicWeek',
    views: {
        basicWeek: {
            titleFormat: 'MMMM D, YYYY'
        },
        listWeek: {
            titleFormat: 'MMMM D, YYYY'
        },
        listSixMonths: {
            type: 'list',
            duration: { months: 6 },
            buttonText: '6 Month List',
            titleFormat: 'MMMM D, YYYY'
        },
    },
    viewRender: renderViewColumns,
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
        element.attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
    },
    eventSources: [eventSource[0],eventSource[1],eventSource[2],eventSource[3], eventSource[4]],
});

// Create Checkboxes
var checkboxContainer = `<ul class='ds-event-categories'>    
<li id='cat99'><label><input id='all-events' type='checkbox' checked>All Events</label></li>
<li id='cat100'><label><input id='conferences' type='checkbox' checked>Conferences</label></li>
<li id='cat101'><label><input id='men' type='checkbox' checked>Men</label></li>
<li id='cat102'><label><input id='women' type='checkbox' checked>Women</label></li>
<li id='cat103'><label><input id='youth' type='checkbox' checked>Youth</label></li>
</ul>`;

// Append it to FullCalendar.
$(".fc-toolbar").after(checkboxContainer);

$("#all-events").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', eventSource[0]);
    } else {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', eventSource[0]);
    }
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
});

$("#conferences").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', eventSource[1]);
    } else {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', eventSource[1]);
    }
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
});

$("#men").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', eventSource[2]);
    } else {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', eventSource[2]);
    }
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
});

$("#women").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', eventSource[3]);
    } else {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', eventSource[3]);
                        }
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
});

$("#youth").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', eventSource[4]);
    } else {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', eventSource[4]);
    }
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
});

function renderViewColumns(view, element) {
    element.find('.fc-day-header').each(function() {
        var theDate = moment($(this).data('date')); /* th.data-date="YYYY-MM-DD" */
        $(this).html(buildDateColumnHeader(theDate));
});

function buildDateColumnHeader(theDate) {
    var container = document.createElement('div');
    var DD = document.createElement('div');
    var ddd = document.createElement('div');
    DD.textContent = theDate.format('DD');
    ddd.textContent = theDate.format('dddd').toUpperCase();
    container.appendChild(DD);
    container.appendChild(ddd);
    DD.className = 'ds-header-day';
    ddd.className = 'ds-header-month';

    return container;
    }
    }
});
```